# How to allow any user can write blog post in orchard cms?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I want to allow create blog post for any login user.
orchard cms use look like for asking questions

Comment: Just assign the right permissions to the 'authenticated' role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps once you have logged in to the Admin area:

1. Click 'Users' from the side menu
2. Click the 'Roles' tab
3. Edit the 'Authenticated' role
4. Scroll down until you find the 'Orchard.Blogs Feature' section.

From there you will see all the settings for Blog Posts.

As you want every logged in user to be able to edit Blog Posts, you most likely want to tick the 4 'Edit' and 'Publish' Blog Post options, but you also have the option of allowing them only to edit their own, if required. See below:

[image]

You also have the option of controlling who can manage individual Blogs, as well as who can delete them.

Hope that helps!